# Как выбрать рандомные буквы из строки без повтора?

Tags: c#

Я сделал это:

```
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvxwyz";

    string GenerateRandomKey(int length)
    {
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            key.Append(alphabet[rnd.Next(0, alphabet.Length - 1)]);

        }
        return key.ToString();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что рандом иногда выводит одинаковые буквы, например **abdbdbZZysdhAA**(большие буквы - повторы). Из-за этого у меня программа не работает, как я понял.

На одной строчке должны быть разные буквы.

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы повторений не было совсем или только у рядом стоящих букв?

Comment: Проще всего «рандомизировать» список, а потом взять первые N букв. Методы «рандомизации» можно найти в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру, вам требуется, чтобы последовательные символы не совпадали. Для этого достаточно исключить прошлое значение индекса из диапазона генерации

```
int rn = -1;      
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (rn < 0)  
         rn = rnd.Next(0, alphabet.Length - 1);
    else
         rn = (rnd.Next(rn + 1,  rn + alphabet.Length - 1)) % alphabet.Length;
    key.Append(alphabet[rn]);
}
```